# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I get the error

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: PageNumber cannot be below 1.
Parameter name: pageNumber
Actual value was 0.
```

When I try pagedlist in my controller.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. But may you consider to improve your question title and text to be more understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

Some more code would be appreciated, but from what I gather it seems as though you're not setting your `PageNumber` variable or it is set to 0. It needs to be 1 by default. Try something like this in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult myAction(int? page) {
    var PageNumber = page ?? 1; // sets PageNumber to 1 if page is null
    ... 
}
```